# How to add a delay to onmousedown

Tags: javascript, settimeout, onfocus

I am trying to set a delay on the mousedown (click) which focuses the newWin.focus in code below:
So in short, the code below works fine. If the popup window is open, it re-focuses on it (bringing it back front) when the user clicks anywhere on the page.

I would like to have a 2 second delay when the user clicks on the page, THEN have it refocus on the new window.

I have spent hours trying to figure this out to no avail using various settimeout's here and there. So, I thought I would show what I have that works and hope someone might explain how my need can be accomplished.

PS: I am still learning my way around javascript and in NO WAY consider myself knowledgeable in the subject.

Thanks in advance!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var newWin;
function openPopup()
{
 newWin=window.open('https://www.somesite/url.php','window','width=400,height=600,scrollbars=0,resizable=1,top=300,left=300');

 document.onmousedown=focusPopup;
 document.onkeyup=focusPopup;
 document.onmousemove=focusPopup;
}
function focusPopup(){
  if(!newWin.closed){
    newWin.focus();
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: are you getting a security error when trying `setTimeout`?

Comment: No. However, Ray answered the question. Thank you for offering your help. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) to your mousedown handler:

```js
document.onmousedown = () => setTimeout(focusPopup, 2000);
```

Comment: Well how about that! Simple and works like a charm. Thank you kindly Ray!

Answer (score 0):

Just use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#syntax) to add the delay.

> The global setTimeout() method sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires.

```js
var newWin;

function openPopup() {
  newWin = window.open('https://www.somesite/url.php', 'window', 'width=400,height=600,scrollbars=0,resizable=1,top=300,left=300');

  document.onmousedown =  function() {
    setTimeout(focusPopup, 2000);
  };
  document.onkeyup = focusPopup;
  document.onmousemove = focusPopup;
}

function focusPopup() {
    if (!newWin.closed) {
      newWin.focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var newWin;
function openPopup()
{
 newWin=window.open('https://www.somesite/url.php','window','width=400,height=600,scrollbars=0,resizable=1,top=300,left=300');

 document.onmousedown=()=>{
   setTimeout(focusPopup,2000)

};
 document.onkeyup=focusPopup;
 document.onmousemove=focusPopup;
}
function focusPopup(){
  if(!newWin.closed){
    newWin.focus();
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Musafiroon, Thank you very much for taking the time to help! I truly appreciate it!! I tried  Ray's answer first, mainly because it was so fast and simple. Turns out it works, so I set it as the accepted answer.